# Sync files between Windows Phone and Skydrive

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, onedrive

Is there an API or any other way to sync a particular format of file between Windows Phone and SkyDrive? I've tried just downloading and uploading files but it doesn't work as I want. I want them to be always in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Here are a couple links on the subject:
http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2011/12/07/skydrive-apis-for-docs-and-photos-now-ready-to-cloud-enable-apps-on-windows-8-windows-phone-and-more.aspx

http://www.itproportal.com/2011/12/13/microsoft-skydrive-api-now-available-third-party-windows-phone-apps/

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/news/Using-SkyDrive-in-your-Windows-Phone-applications-part-1